# Find and replace only between searched patterns

Tags: indentation, substitute, find

Editing large HTML file. Would like to do something like:

```
:/<blockquote>/,/<\/blockquote>/s/^\(\s\s\+\)\(<[^>].\{-}>\)/\1  \2/g
```

So basically just trying to indent all  between the  tag lines. I thought this was possible, but perhaps I mangled the syntax.

Thanks,

Comment: This line works for me (at least, it does *something*.) Maybe the problem is that it doesn't do *exactly* what you wanted? In that case, can you please explain what you wanted it to do that's different from what it's doing right now? Please edit your question to add an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Is `sed` an option?

```
sed -r '/<blockquote>/,/<\/blockquote>/{s/^(\s\s\+)(<[^>].\{-}>)/\1  \2/g}'
```

Comment: I mean, technically, probably, but considering this is [vi.se] you probably should add some information regarding how you could do this with vi/vim.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to indent html, use the indent operator `=` with the inner-tag text object `it`:

1. Place your cursor on the tag whose contents need indenting
2. Press `=it`